# How to style content rendered with ngx-markdown?

Tags: css, angular, markdown

I'm building a blog with Angular and I want to create my posts with Markdown. I intend to use `ngx-markdown` to render them. Right now I'm creating a "post creation" component. The thing is I wish to apply some styling on the markdown, but I can't. This is my component:

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <h1 class="header">New post</h1>
  <button>Send</button>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="post-editor">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input class="title-field" type="text" name="title"
      placeholder="E.g: Introduction to Programming" autocomplete="off"
      [(ngModel)]="post.title"
    >
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="post.content"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="post-preview">
    <markdown class="markdown" [data]="getPostAsString()" ngPreserveWhitespaces>
    </markdown>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

interface Post {
  title: string;
  content: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-post',
  templateUrl: './create-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-post.component.css']
})
export class CreatePostComponent implements OnInit {
  post: Post = {
    title: 'Introduction to Programming',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet...'
  };

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getPostAsString(): string {
    return `# ${this.post.title}\n` + this.post.content;
  }
}
```

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
label {
  font-size: 18px;
}
input, textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
input {
  height: 25px;
}
textarea {
  height: 300px;
}
button {
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 75%;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.header-container, .main-container {
  display: flex;
}
.post-editor, .post-preview {
  flex: 1;
}
.post-preview {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.post-editor {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.header {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.title-field {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Note this rule:

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

I applied it for test purposes. The header on top of the page that says "New Post" gets styled (blue), but the markdown one does not. I also tried using different selectors such as `markdown h1` and `.post-preview h1`, but none worked. Why it isn't working and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally libray css changes is working in `styles.css` you should try to add you css code block to `styles.css`

```
.post-preview h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could style them in the component. Doing in on the styles.css can lead to global conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Angular you can apply the styles when you use `::ng-deep`:

```
.post-preview ::ng-deep h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```